# Google Directions API and android

Tags: android, directions, google-directions-api

In my app I use Google Directions API to draw a route from point A to point B on my map.

When I try to get my route I get 403 with message "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.", but this issue arises only when I try to restrict my API key to be used by android apps. When I drop the restriction everything works fine. Package and fingerprint are correct, the issue is actual for both debug and release builds. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, can't you just work with not restricting? Could be a bug

Comment: This really seems to be a bug. Try posting your bug on direction api.

Comment: Thanks for replies! I'll post this issue to directions and will use api without restrictions for now

Answer (score 0):

You should set your API key to not restricting. I had the same problem but fixed it this way.